# Protection formula looping in appscript

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet-protection

I have the data of 300*8 cell in that 3rd row contains email on based of that i m **protecting row by appscript**. I m new to appscript and no background of coding or computer.

I have made the formula and **normally running in individual row No** but if I adding in to for **loop** it is not getting work

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  
  var master = ss.getSheetByName("Master sheet");//in this sheet data present

  ss.setActiveSheet(master, true);
 
  for(i=0;i=10;i ++ ); {
  var range  = master.getRange(i+5,3).getValue();
  var protection = master.getRange(i+5,1,1,6).protect();
  var remove = protection.getEditors();
       protection.setDescription(range).removeEditors(remove).addEditor(range);
}
}
```

If I put value instead of **loop var i** at row value then it work properly

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const master = ss.getSheetByName("Master sheet");

  for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    var value = master.getRange(i + 5, 3).getValue();
    var protection = master.getRange(i + 5, 1, 1, 6).protect();
    var remove = protection.getEditors();
    protection.setDescription(value).removeEditors(remove).addEditor(value);
  }
}
```